# AngularJS Insert in Web Api is null

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to put together my first CRUD app using AngularJS and Asp.Net Web Api. I have setup the controller with a newMember object:

```
 $scope.newMember = {};
```

And then call the insert in the factory method as:

```
dataService.insertMember($scope.newMember);
```

This calls the method in the dataService:

```
 var _insertMember = function(member) {
    return $http.post("/api/clubmembers/", member);
};
```

which fires the Web Api Post method

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]PersonViewModel member)
    {
        //if (_repo.AddClubMember(member) && _repo.Save())
        if (_repo.AddClubMember(member) && _repo.Save())
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, member);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

I have checked the data in the Angular part of the app and the correct data is passed via $scope.newMember, but when it reaches the Web Api Post method the member parameter is always Null.

If I modify the controller method to the following it passes the data to the Post method as expected:

```
var testData2 = {
        FirstName: $scope.newMember.FirstName,
        LastName: $scope.newMember.LastName
    };
    var a = 1;
    dataService.insertMember(testData2);
```

Is it possible to pass $scope.newMember as the parameter or do I have to fill in the details as of the amended code?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code carefully, I would say *(based on your experience described in the question)* there will be some typo.

#### Call with explicit `{}` - empty object

If you will call your service like this:

```
dataService.insertMember({}); // just created empty object
```

you will get instantiated object on your API Post method `PersonViewModel member`

#### Call with explicit `null` or `undefined`

but in case, that you will call one of these

```
dataService.insertMember(null);
dataService.insertMember(undefined);
```

the API Post method will be provided with NULL.

#### typo *(incorrect property name)*, i.e. undefined

And what that means? that you most likely, somewhere in the call chain used something like this

```
$scope.newMember ...
...
dataService.insertMember($scope.newMemberXXX);
```

where `newMemberXXX` represents any **undefined** property, resulting in undefined to be passed

Comment: Thanks, but I've gone through the code and all properties match

Comment: Have just noticed I had a property and function called $scope.newMember

Comment: Yes that would be the issue. The point is, that the $scope.newMember in fact is not what we expect...

Comment: Great to see that you manage to make it running. Enjoy combination web api and angular, good choice ;)

Comment: Thanks, really enjoying it - makes life nice and easy

Answer (score 0):

If you add `FirstName` and `LastName` properties to  `newMember` it should work fine:

```
$scope.newMember = {};
$scope.newMember.FirstName = "First Name";
$scope.newMember.LastName = "Last Name";

dataService.insertMember($scope.newMember);
```

Thing is, `$scope.newMember` has to match the properties and structure of `PersonViewModel` for the Web Api to be able to match the two types.

Let us know if this works.

Comment: Hi, tried this but the same error. Only way I've found around is to set the values at Post time